# Undefined al acceder al atributo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy creando la parte de update de un formulario en Reactjs cuando accedo al objeto que es consumido mediante props en el componente postForm este me muestra el objeto sin ningun problema incluso todos sus propiedades pero cuando intento acceder a la propiedad del objeto me aparece el error 
***TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined***
como si el objeto pasase a estar solo declarado. 
adjunto codigo de el componente **PostForm.js**:

```
export class PostForm extends React.Component {


state = {
    title: '',
    content: '',
    post: [],
    saved: false
}



handlePost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const data = { [name]: value }
    const newData = {...this.state.post, ...data}

    this.setState({
        post: newData
    })
}


handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const post = this.state.post;
    this.props.addNewPost(post);
    this.setState({
        saved: true
    })

}



render(){
    if(this.state.saved === true) {
        return <Redirect to='/' />
    }
    **console.log(this.props.post.title)**

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <form className="w-50" onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title" value={this.props.post} onChange={e => this.handlePost(e)} className="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Titulo"/>

                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <textarea name="content" onChange={e => this.handlePost(e)} className="form-control"  rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

El objeto post es pasado a través de props desde el componente de clase App.
como ven despues del metodo render esta llamado el objeto si lo llamo sin acceder a la propiedad title me aparece: 
**{title: "awdawd", content: "awdawd", id: 1, slug: "awdawd"}**

se entiende que es el posteo que se hizo para la demostración.

Comment: No se si tenga que ver con tu error, pero `value={this.props.post}` no debería funcionar, por lo que tengo entendido, no puedes pasar un objeto como valor de un input. Además si `this.props.post` se muestra como `undefined`, es porque efectivamente no siempre está seteado, deberías modificar la lógica de tu componente para soportar ese caso.

Comment: @AlterLagos Hola estimado gracias por tu respuesta. lo pude arreglar gracias

Comment: Me alegro. Si has sabido arreglar, podrías compartir tu solución como respuesta, por si a futuro alguien se encuentra con un problema similar al tuyo. Saludos

Comment: @ricardoleivasikic mi recomendación es que uses los Hooks de react tendrás menos problemas y un código mas limpio.